Excel Ribbon Issues - Always needs to be reimported
I've created a ribbon that I want to permanently attach to Excel. Here's a snippet:
<mso:cmd app="Excel" dt="1" slr="0" />
<mso:customUI xmlns:x2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui/macro"
    xmlns:x1="Dna.9be7baec408250e2b8d7244b31b019b7.0"
    xmlns:mso="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <mso:ribbon>
        <mso:qat/>
        <mso:tabs>
            <mso:tab idQ="mso:TabDrawInk" visible="false"/>
            <mso:tab idQ="mso:TabView">
                <mso:group idQ="mso:GroupViewShowHide" visible="false"/>
            </mso:tab>
            <mso:tab idQ="x1:tabMain"/>
            <mso:tab id="mso_c1.3E378B7A" label="BAL" insertAfterQ="x1:tabMain">
                <mso:group id="mso_c2.3E378B7A" label="BAL" autoScale="false"/>
                <mso:group id="mso_c1.3E394445" label="Time" autoScale="false">
                    <mso:button idQ="x2:K:ThisWorkbook.xlsm_Today_0_27D800BE" label="Today" imageMso="ListMacros" onAction="Today" visible="true" size="normal"/>
                    <mso:button idQ="x2:K:ThisWorkbook.xlsm_Year_1_27D800BE" label="Year" imageMso="ListMacros" onAction="Year" visible="true" size="normal"/>
                    <mso:button idQ="x2:K:ThisWorkbook.xlsm_Season_2_27D800BE" label="Season" imageMso="ListMacros" onAction="Season" visible="true" size="normal"/>
                    <mso:button idQ="x2:K:ThisWorkbook.xlsm_Quarter_3_27D800BE" label="Quarter" imageMso="ListMacros" onAction="Quarter" visible="true" size="normal"/>
                    <mso:button idQ="x2:K:ThisWorkbook.xlsm_Month_4_27D800BE" label="Month" imageMso="ListMacros" onAction="Month" visible="true" size="normal"/>
                </mso:group>
        </mso:tabs>
    </mso:ribbon>
</mso:customUI>

However every morning I need to reimport the ribbon as the formatting either changes, or it drops from my excel completely if I close excel entirely. How can I attach the ribbon permanently to Excel? Secondly how can I not have its formatting change throughout the day. For the formatting, when I import it, it looks like

But if I then go to another sheet it looks like:

As you can see from the ribbon code I have tried many things to force this auto scaling.

I'll add a function to QXL to reload your ribbon.. ;)

I'm not sure how you are 'importing' the Ribbon XML at present? However, if you want a custom Ribbon tab (or part of a tab ... or multiple tabs) to be present in Excel no matter which Workbook is open or active (or even if no Workbook is open or active) then you need to:

Create an AddIn ... see Creating an Excel Add-in
Add the Ribbon XML code to the AddIn ... I recommend using Office RibbonX Editor

... note I have no link with either website / tool.
As for your Ribbon changing when you go to another Sheet, the way the Ribbon displays is dynamic and partly controlled by the host application (ie Excel in this case). As you seem to have lots of button controls in your Ribbon, you might want to either use multiple tabs and split the buttons over them or possibly use different types of control such as a DropDown or SplitButton which allows you to group multiple 'settings' into one control.
